# Create accounting system in Meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, nosql

I want to create an accounting system. I am learning Meteor. But I have seen that Meteor does not support relational databases so I don't know how to have a data structure in which an user can create a budget, create multiple accounting numbers "inside"/related to this budget, and multiple budget lines on these accounting numbers.

Normally, I will use foreign keys, having a table `budget` with an id field, a table `accounting_numbers` with an id field and a foreign key referencing `budget`, and a table `budget_line` with a foreign key referencing `accounting_numbers`.

But if I cannot reference other tables in MongoDB, I am kind of confused how to create even simple web apps like an accounting/budget system. I wonder if the best option is to also save budget id and budget name in each object in `accounting_numbers` but what if the user wants to change the budget name. Does he/she have to edit the name in all objects in `accounting_numbers`? And if the objects `budget_line` belongs to an object in `accounting_numbers` which further belongs to an object in `budget`, how much data will I then need to store in each object in `budget_line`?

Answer (score 1):

You can still create multiple "tables" in Mongo aka collections, and simulate relational structure. As far as structure goes, Mongo can map very closely in struture to a relational database. The only issue (and it's a huge issue) is that Mongo does not support joins across these "tables", therefore you would need to perform these joins manually either in your code or having an ORM do it for you. Mongo also does not have transactions across "tables", so that is again, something you'd need to painstakingly implement manually or through a library.

That being said, when building anything it's best to use the right tool for the job, and Meteor is probably not the tool you'd want for something like this. Mongo is great for apps where you're dealing with non-relational data. Accounting data is nearly always relational. I know Mongo is "webscale" and all, but for the love of god, please use a relational database.

Comment: I can just save so much time using Meteor since I want to make the app change in real-time. It's a quite simple app; however, quite large datasets. Couldn't I make a schema `Budget` with accounting_numbers as children objects and budget lines as children objects to accounting_numbers or will it be too messy?

Comment: Yes, you could. As for whether it will be messy or not, it depends on the queries you're going to want to run now, and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at "Space Elephant - PostgresSQL implementation for Meteor". Instead of using MongoDB you can use PostrgreSQL as a database, without losing the main benefits provided by Meteor. Mainly "Reactivity" and "Latency Compensation".

There are also some packages you can use to simulate the functionalities of relational databases. One example could be "Meteor Collection Hooks". This package let´s you append functionality before and after a "Mongo.Collection" call. So, for example you could use it like this:

```
Budget.after.update(function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifiers, options){
  if (this.previous.budgetName !== doc.budgetName){
    AccountingName.update({budgetId: doc._id}, {$set: { budgetName: doc.budgetName }}, { multi: true });
  }
});
```

I also agree with Jamgreen answer, but if you really want to use Meteor I believe that using this package and getting to know MongoDB a little bit more you could implement your App with ease.

Hope this helps.